# Passing Strings to /bin/login

Tags: bash, login, tty, ncurses

I'm in the process of creating a login wrapper for /bin/login so that when you boot Linux you get a TUI Login instead of the bland login on the tty console. This will be just a bash script for this wrapper, however I'm wondering how / if can pass the users username and password to /bin/login in one or two lines.

Todo this I would think you could do

```
echo "username/npassword" | login
```

But it didn't work. At least that's what I'm getting on my terminal. I've considered except shell but it spawns under the user. Can anyone redirect me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You c ould use expect to automate the process, altenatively, you could write username and password as variables, and call them in your script. You could also read them in from user input. I think the simplest way would be to use epect though, which can easily handle things like dealys, and stepping thought interactive processes.

an example login script with expect could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#./script user passwd
spawn login  [lindex $argv 0]
set passID [lindex $argv 1]
expect "Password:"
send "$passID\r"
spawn echo "lol\r\r"
expect eof
```

There are many ways to do this task, what ever you choose, I would avoid saving the password inside the script if possible.